# Copy x element from a map to another one with generic

Tags: java, generics

i search a way to copy x element from a map to another.
i tried this code

```
private void newMapElement( Map<?, ?> userMap, Map<?, ?> newUserMap, int maxSize)
{
    int i = 0;
    for ( Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : userMap.entrySet() )
    {
        newUserMap.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
            i++;
            if ( i == maxSize)
            {
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

but java don't seem to like the put.

Any idea?

Comment: Is you getting any exception ? Implemented newUserMap with HasHmap or any other map implemetation ?

Comment: Syntax error is: The method put(capture#3-of ?, capture#4-of ?) in the type Map<capture#3-of ?,capture#4-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#5-of ?, capture#8-of ?)

Comment: the you have to define same data types in both maps. Example one map is Map<String,String> means another also Map<String,String>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use `? super T` for **newUserMap** as wildcards with super(wildcards with upperbounds) would allow you to add elements into your map,your code should be something like below:

```
private <T> void newMapElement( Map<? extends T, ? extends T> userMap, Map<? super T, ? super T> newUserMap, int maxSize)
{
    int i = 0;
    for ( Map.Entry<? extends T, ? extends T> entry : userMap.entrySet() )
    {
        newUserMap.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
            i++;
            if ( i == maxSize)
            {
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do key and value types have to be the same?

Comment: @newacct well, they could differ, but i was only giving a test case scenario:)